# Sequence of Functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm having difficulty determining where this sequence of functions $\displaystyle f(n,x)=\frac{x^n}{(1+x^n)}$ converges, and whether it converges uniformly.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you rewrite it as $f_n(x) = 1/(1/x^n + 1)$. Does that seem to help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? And do you want uniform convergence on the whole real line? Or perhaps on $[0,1]$ or $(1,\infty)$?

Comment: @belmont Any feedback on the answers??

Answer (score 2):

You can see that if we set

$${f_n}\left( x \right) = \frac{{{x^n}}}{{1 + {x^n}}}$$

$${f_n}\left( x \right) \to 1  \Leftrightarrow x>1 $$

$${f_n}\left( x \right) \to \frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow x=1 $$

$${f_n}\left( x \right) \to 0 \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq x < 1$$

Answer (score 1):

not on the entire $\mathbb{R}$ of course, since the limit function is not continuous.

and it is uniform on $[0, 1-\varepsilon]$ and on $[1+\varepsilon, +\infty)$ by compaire it with $(1-\varepsilon)^n$ and $(1+\varepsilon)^n/(1+(1+\varepsilon)^n)$ resp.